# Replace stock cannondale bad boy jekyll saddle

Tags: saddle, cannondale

I am looking to replace the stock saddle of an old cannondale bad boy jekyll with something more comfortable. The local store tells me that since cannondale does not produce their own saddles, I should buy a third party saddle from them. Is this true? Can anyone recommend a saddle, cannondale or otherwise, that will be more comfortable yet is still forward angled and not too wide?

[1](http://www.cannondale.com/2012/gear/component/2012-quick-saddle)
[2](http://www.cannondale.com/2012/gear/component/2012-quick-comfort-saddle)
[3](http://www.cannondale.com/2012/gear/component/2012-bad-boy-saddle)
[4](http://www.cannondale.com/2012/gear/component/2012-tesoro-saddle)
[5](http://www.cannondale.com/2012/gear/component/2012-hooligan-saddle)
[6](http://www.cannondale.com/2012/gear/component/2012-all-mountain-saddle)
[7](http://www.cannondale.com/2012/gear/component/2012-synapse-saddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saddles are personal. There is no way for anyone to give you a good and reliable recommendation that can be guaranteed.

Cannondale, like most manufacturers, buys and rebrands saddles from other companies. The stock saddle will be very basic, usually, and replacing is usually a good idea.

Third party saddle will have no problem fitting on your bike, and I would recommend you speak to the guys at your LBS and let them recommend a good saddle for your riding style and body type.

They know you, and any specific saddle we suggest would be know more than a general guess.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Regardless of the type/style, is there a brand you can recommend?

Comment: Selle Italia, specifically the Flite Gel Flow. Or Fizik.